# Повідомлення "Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references"

Tags: discussion, rules

До моєї [відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/201/69) тепер підвішений банер:

> Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please edit to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

Це у нас тепер до всіх постів без посилань буде така штука ліпитися? Треба сюди посилання на англо-український словник додати чи як?

Текст відповіді такий:

> Не знаю щодо найкращого перекладу, але "second to none" дослівно означає - якщо "цей об'єкт" поставити на друге місце, на перше місце не знайдеш що поставити (з чого зрозуміло що кращого просто немає).
>
> Тобто **кращого не знайдеш** або **кращого не знайти**.

Answer (score 1):

Banners are set manually by moderators. Here's the [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) explaining the purpose of banners, in general. Simply speaking, these are equivalents of Wikipedia's banners `{{Unreferenced}}`, `{{RefImprove}}` and so on.

Also, banners allow avoid large number of users' comments containing demands for citations, denials, etc.

In this particular case, I was in a process of reviewing site's content and placed banners on some posts of lower quality.

Once the post is improved, the OP is encouraged to **raise a flag** attracting a mod's attention to review the post and remove the flag.
You're a Mod, too, so you can remove the banner by yourself; but I kindly ask to improve the post first. :-)